# Mostrar datos de otra tabla relacionada con MySQL, Java web JSP

Tags: mysql, sql

Quiero mostrar un dato en mi pagina web que se encuentra en otra tabla, por ejemplo, tengo mi base de datos relacionada de esta forma:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

donde mi llave foranea en mi tabla usuario es el idPerfil de la tabla perfil,
por lo cual mis tablas en MySQL, ya con datos registrados se ven de esta forma:
**TABLA USUARIO**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y mi **TABLA PERFIL**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo que quiero saber es como podre hacerle para que en mi sitio web aparezca el **nombrePerfil** de acuerdo con la relacion, en lugar de que muestre el idPerfil **1** muestre el nombrePerfil **ADMINISTRADOR** lo mismo con el idPerfil 2 muestre **EMPLEADO** y no el idPerfil

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi codigo donde mando a llamar los datos en la tabla

```html
<c:forEach var="dato" items="${lista}">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>${dato.idUsuario}</td>
                                    <td>${dato.claveUsuario}</td>
                                    <td>${dato.nombre}</td>
                                    <td>${dato.apellido}</td>
                                    <td>${dato.email}</td>
                                    <td>${dato.contrasena}</td>
                                    <td>${dato.idPerfil}</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <a href="editar.htm?id=${dato.idUsuario}" class="btn btn-warning">Editar</a>
                                        <a href="delete.htm?id=${dato.idUsuario}" class="btn btn-danger">Eliminar</a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </c:forEach>
```

Estas son mis consultas SQL, La de mostrar los datos

```html
@RequestMapping("index.htm")
    public ModelAndView Listar()
    {
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM usuario";
        datos = this.jdbcTemplate.queryForList(sql);
        mav.addObject("lista", datos);
        mav.setViewName("index");
        return mav;
    }
```

y mi consulta para insertar los datos

```html
@RequestMapping(value = "agregar.htm", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView Agregar(Persona p)
    {
        String sql = "INSERT INTO usuario(claveUsuario, nombre, apellido, email, contrasena) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
        this.jdbcTemplate.update(sql,p.getClave(), p.getNom(), p.getApe(), p.getCorreo(), p.getPass());
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/index.htm");
    }
```

faltaría agregar el campo nombrePerfil a mi tabla usuario para que lo muestre
Cualquier ayuda se los agradecería

Comment: Hola necesitamos ver tu consulta SQL por favor

Comment: @Aprendiz edite mi publicacion mostrando la consulta SQL, mostrar e insertar

Comment: No haces algún `JOIN` para obtener los datos de la tabla que muestras?

Comment: @Aprendiz No, solo hago el select directo a la tabla usuario, faltaría hacer un inner join? o algo así?

Comment: Si dame un minuto y te ayudo

Comment: Muchas gracias! espero

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Considero que debes hacer uso de un `JOIN` puesto que tienes 2 tablas vinculadas; una por su llave primaria apuntando a la llave foránea de otra.

Entonces pudieras componerla de este modo:

```
SELECT usuario.idUsuario, 
       usuario.nombre,
       usuario.apellido,
       usuario.email,
       usuario.contrasena,
       perfil.nombrePerfil
FROM usuario
JOIN perfil ON usuario.idPerfil = perfi.idPerfil;
```

Donde:

- Seleccionas todas las columnas que deseas recuperar de ambas tablas, por medio de la sintaxis de `tabla.columna`
- Indicas en el `FROM` la tabla usuario
- Usas `JOIN` para indicar que la igualación de columnas ocurrirá `ON` la llave primaria de `perfil` llamada `idPerfil` que apunta a la llave foránea de la tabla `usuario` llamada `idPerfil`
- Haciendo uso de `JOIN` o `INNER JOIN` vas a indicar que te recupere los registros de las dos tablas siempre y cuando tengan un registro en común

Comment: Perfecto, me ha funcionado!! muchas gracias

Comment: Podrían mostrar como les quedo por favor, es que a mi no me sale, creo que es el el archivo de JSP de Lista